# Swift and Firebase Real-Time-Database: How do I get the number of objects?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just started learning Swift and I am trying to display fruits, which I added into my Real-Time-Firebase, on a list. I am stuck getting the number of fruits out of my Database. 
Here is my Database in JSON:

```
  "fruits" : {
    "apple" : {
      "price" : 4,
      "rate" : 6
    },
    "banana" : {
      "price" : 2,
      "rate" : 5
    },
    "orange" : {
      "price" : 10,
      "rate" : 9
    }
  }
```

I know how to read and write Data but don't know how to get the number of Fruits in Swift. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine the number of child nodes in a snapshot, use its [`DataSnapshot.childrenCount` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#childrencount). So something like:

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.child("fruits").observe(.value) { snapshot in
  print(snapshot.childrenCount)
}
```

Note that this loads all data under `fruits` from the database to your app, and performs the count inside your application. There is no operator to perform the count of the server and only get that result.

Comment: You have made my day!

Comment: @baken Excellent answer (as expected, lol) however, consider the dataset size. As Frank mentions. observing that node by .value reads in ALL of the data in the node. While for smaller datasets that's fine, if you have 100,000 users plus all of their data to count, that could overwhelm a device *and* it will take time to read in all of that data. A solution is to keep a counter in a separate node and as children (like a user) is added or removed from the /users node, update the counter +1 or -1. That makes working with gigantic data sets a snap (and fast) since you only need to read one node.